# #Name error in excel sheet

Tags: excel

I have a `csv` file which is filled automatically through a `java` programm. I have a line which have the following text when I open the text in `Notepad++`:

```
-LRB- from the PMI Practice Standard for Work Breakdown Structures , Oct 2000 -RRB- '',"no","f1_FRAG:1.0","f2_specialChar:1.0","f3:15.0","f4:7.0","f5:0.0","f6:2.0","f7:0.0","f8:3.7612001156935624","f9:7.0","f10:1.0","f11:1.0","f12:0.0","f13:0.0","f14:0.0,"f15_ROOT:1.0","f16_specialChar:1.0","f17_NOTHING:1.0","f18_IN:1.0""
```

But when I open it in excel sheet, there are two problems:

1) When I click on the cell, I see `#Name` error and any click on the page causes an error. I even can't close the excel window normally. I also sometimes see something like `=A228` or `=B223` when I click on the cell. It sounds to be read as a formula, but it actually isn't.

2) The row is not shown completely. I can't see this part when I open the file using `office excel`:

```
",f15_ROOT:1.0","f16_specialChar:1.0","f17_NOTHING:1.0","f18_IN:1.0"".
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the row starts with a **`-`** (minus sign), Excel is expecting a formula.

Manually, you could either:

- add an **`'`** (apostrophe) at the beginning of the line (which tells Excel that the cell contains text), or
- Format the cell as **text** : Right-click the cell → `Format Cells` → `Number` tab → `Text`

Ideally, to prevent this issue in the future, the Java program which generates the `.CSV` file should be changed to enclose text fields with **`"`** double quotation marks.

Oddly, that is the only field in your example that *isn't* surrounded by double quotes.

```
"-LRB- from the PMI Practice Standard for Work Breakdown Structures , Oct 2000 -RRB- ''","no","f1_FRAG:1.0","f2_specialChar:1.0","f3:15.0","f4:7.0","f5:0.0","f6:2.0","f7:0.0","f8:3.7612001156935624","f9:7.0","f10:1.0","f11:1.0","f12:0.0","f13:0.0","f14:0.0,"f15_ROOT:1.0","f16_specialChar:1.0","f17_NOTHING:1.0","f18_IN:1.0""
```

At the **minimum**, double-quotes should the used around any fields that begin with a symbol or contain a comma (like above).

```
1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"
```

The double-quotes will be recognized and removed by most apps that open CSV's.

> - Any field may be quoted (that is, enclosed within double-quote characters). Some fields must be quoted, as specified in following
>   rules.
>
>   `"1997","Ford","E350"`
> - Fields with embedded commas or double-quote characters must be quoted.
>
>   `1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"`
> - Each of the embedded double-quote characters must be represented by a pair of double-quote characters.
>
>   `1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck"`

.

### More about Comma Separated Value files:

- [Wikipedia: CSV Files - Basic Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules)
- [RFC 2046 Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046)
- [RFC4180 Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)

.

Surprisingly, I can't find any reference document from Microsoft that mentions starting text cells with an apostrophe. (I guess it's a secret, so if anyone asks, you didn't hear it from me.)  :-)

The reason you are getting the #NAME error specifically is because Excel figures you're trying to enter a formula (because of the minus sign) but it doesn't recognize the *Name* of the function ("LRB")